# Want to be able to validate the Child field to not exceed the Parent field (multiple child records and multiple fields)

Tags: trigger, case, before-trigger, roll-up-summary, aggregateresult

I'm trying to write a trigger that would basically identify the value of a field on a parent Case. Then, make sure that the value that is entered in the child field (on ALL child cases together) is not greater than the parent field value. There could be multiple child Cases. There are multiple fields to validate, but they are validated individually (car__c, bus__c, train__c, etc..).

Ex: Parent.Car__c = 10; 
 Child1.Car__c = 5; 
 Child2.Car__c = 3;
Child3.Car__c = 6; <-- trigger error message. exceeded the total amount.

This is my current code. It's not complete because I wanted to get it working based on one field first then try include the additional fields. One problem though, I keep getting an error!: "NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"

```
trigger ScanExceedField on Case (before insert, before update) {

  Case c;
//set<Id> parentIdsList = new Set<Id>(); 
List<Case> parentIdsList = [SELECT Id FROM Case];

if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)
{
    Map<Id, AggregateResult> scanSumsMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT ParentId Id, SUM(Car__c) scanSum FROM Case WHERE ParentId IN :parentIdsList GROUP BY ParentId]);

    Decimal parentScanUsed;
    for(Case child : [SELECT Id, parentId FROM Case where parentId != NUll]){
        parentScanUsed = (Decimal)(scanSumsMap.get(child.ParentId).get('scanSum')) == null ? 0 : (Decimal)(scanSumsMap.get(child.ParentId).get('scanSum'));

            if(parentScanUsed > c.Car__C){
                c.Car__c.addError('you cannot exceed the amount');
            } 
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You're querying the *entire database* in your trigger. You will eventually run in to problems doing this. You need to filter your queries by the records in the current trigger context.

Comment: This is only being done in my personal Developer sandbox, at the moment. I will limit it based on Record Type later after I can get past the error.

Answer (score 0):

Up top, you had `Case c`, but you never assigned a value to it, so it was null later:

```
        if(parentScanUsed > c.Car__C){
```

It's likely that you actually meant to use `child` instead:

```
        if(parentScanUsed > child.Car__C){
```

Comment: even when I comment out that entire if statement, I get the same error. I tried what you stated and still.. same error.

Comment: @D.henderson c is still null. You're going to want to start by getting the parentid values from the cases in the trigger, running the query, then checking the results. I wrote a post about this that might help you: http://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html

Comment: I commented out the object and the variable.. still error. In the List following that, I'm grabbing all of the Case records (I'm in my dev sandbox so it's fine. I will limit by record type later). I will take a look at your link.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I looked at your blog entry and modified my code based on the example you have there. I tries running a portion of it in Execute Anon. and received this error: "Invalid loop variable type expected SObject was Case" Code: Set<Id> parentCaseId = new Set<Id>();
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
            parentCaseId.add(record.parentId);}
}
 parentCaseId.remove(null);

Comment: @D.henderson In exec anon, Trigger.new/old/newMap/oldMap are null and of an undefined type. You can't really use these variables outside of a trigger context.